# Is there a way for Braille-Cribbage players to find each other?

Tags: cribbage

It's already known that Cribbage can be played by blind people by using Braille-cards, but what I need to know is whether there is a database for Braille-players to get together in their local areas.

The Blind-Foundation here in Hawaii can not find any other blind-cribbage players, so I post here to hopefully find a blind-cribbage partner here in Honolulu.

Comment: It might be more reasonable to find other blind card players and teach them cribbage. Who knows, maybe you'll learn some other games that you'll enjoy, too.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't have much luck because I couldn't take the time to sign out and getting recommendations not based on my preferences is apparently quite hard. But have you tried [MeetUp](http://www.meetup.com/)? On the continent I know it's a very popular website for finding local gamers. You might be able to use MeetUp as Hao Ye suggests to find a blind meet up and see if anyone is interested in cribbage. The best I could find was this [Singles Group](http://www.meetup.com/MatchUp-Oahu/) but there might be others and you might be able to create one if you're interetsed. You could also scan [your local subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Honolulu/).